# Making a note taking app with no code tools, Can I get an API to make the notes or do I have to code it myself?

Tags: android, ios, api, mobile

I'm a UX designer, who is trying to make a note-taking app that can make voice notes, text notes and just notes in general. My only challenge with the no-code platforms is finding a component and not knowing what the 'action' is called to 'create a new something'  Like create a new card with text. Create new voice notes etc.
If there are free Api's for this that would be great.
Alternatively, a youtube tutorial would be good, please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With less expenditure there are plenty of coded apps on github. But if you want to learn how to code a simply note app, I suggest to watch this [video](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-sticky-notes-application-in-android-studio/) for creating a "Note-App" and also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUVMebxypzQ&ab_channel=YoutCode-ProgrammingTutorials) for making a "Memo-App". After that you can implement function like voice messages, but start simple with Strings.

Comment: You are welcome.  Tick it as the right answer if it helped you, to help others. Thanks and happy coding! :)